# Problem in Multiplication theorem.

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $10$ black and $5$ white balls. Two black
>   balls are drawn from the urn and one after other.
>   $E$ and $F$ denote respectively the events that first and second ball drawn are black.

How do I find $P(F|E)$?

I think $P(F|E) =$ the probability of occurrence of $F$ when $E$ is taken as sample space.
When $E$ took place we had a black ball which should now be sample space for $F$. So, now $P(F|E)$ should be  $1$.
But book says $P(F|E) = 9/14$.
where am I wrong.

In all questions I did in previous exercise of my book I used $P(A|B) =$ Probability of occurrence of $A$ when $B$ is taken as sample space.
So if I already have done event $E$, now I should have only a black ball in my hand. Now $P(F|E)$ should mean I take out next black black ball from my black ball obtained in $E$. This gives probability of $1$.
Another way to find $P(F|E)$ can be by $n\left\lvert F \cap E\right\lvert / n\left\lvert E \right\lvert$ .
Can you please explain using this method?

Comment: After the black ball is drawn, you have $14$ balls left of which $9$ are black.

Comment: But why E is not taken as sample space.

Comment: The sample space is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ where the first is black. Not really a useful way to think in this case. It is clear that the conditional probability the second is black given the first is cannot be $1$, there are lots of white balls left.

Comment: That's not right. The problem is with respect to the balls in the **urn** not from you hand. That is what is **explicitly** stated in the problem. We would need more context regarding the previous problems to be able to determine the issue.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Here is a [guide to some of the tricky maths markup](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @André and probablyme: I agree with you both but I don't get why my answer by using my definition is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urn contained $10$ black and $5$ white balls, then two were drawn without replacement.

> In all questions I did in previous exercise of my book I used $P(A\mid B)=$ Probability of occurrence of $A$ when $B$ is taken as sample space. So if I already have done event $E$, now I should have only a black ball in my hand. Now $P(F|E)$ should mean I take out next black black ball from my black ball obtained in $E$. This gives probability of $1$.

No, the second ball must be drawn from those remaining in the **urn**.

There are $140$ ways to obtain event $E$:   That is to draw one of the $10$ black balls then draw any of the remaining $14$ balls.   That is your sample space.   $\mathsf P(F\mid E)$ is thus the probability measure that given we have one of these $140$ equally-probable outcomes we *also* obtain event $F$ - that the second ball is *also* black.

$$\mathsf P(F\mid E) =\frac{\mathsf P(E\cap F)}{\mathsf P(E)} = \frac{90}{140}$$

Comment: @AnubhavGoel The probability space consists of a draw of **two** balls from the urn; and there is a total of $15\times 14$ ways to do this.  Of *these*, $10\times 14$ have a black ball drawn first and any ball drawn second.  That is event $E$ - that the first of *two* balls drawn is black.

Answer (score 1):

Close. Conditioning on $E$ means that I tell you on the first draw, you got a black ball. Thus in the next turn, what is the probability that you get a black?
Well, there are only 14 balls left, and 9 of them are black. Thus
$$P(F|E) = \frac{9}{14}$$
using the logic above. You can check by hand using Bayes' rule.

Comment: My question still stands why you did not took E as sample space.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel What do you mean by that? Can you write it out?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: $E$ was taken as a sample space. In $E$, we've chosen one black ball, so there are $9$ black balls and $5$ white balls left for the second choice.

Comment: @robjon: if you took E as sample space you have only 1 black ball as sample space which you took out.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel No, the correct sample space $E$ is the one everyone is describing about the remaining balls in the urn. The sample space $E$ is **not** what is in your hand.